# How do you iterate through the vertices of a geometry in threejs v128+?

Tags: three.js

I'm looking at some old code that does the following to slightly randomize the vertices of a geometry:

```
  let geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(size, 1);
  geometry.vertices.forEach(function(v) {
    v.x += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
    v.y += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
    v.z += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
  });
```

But in more recent versions of threejs, there is no vertices property on geometry. So how would you achieve this with modern versions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I settled on. It seems threejs changed by no longer storing each vertex as a single point but, rather, having multiple points (on different faces) meet at the same vertex. So to warp the dodecahedron, I had to first identify each point on the same vertex and modify them in the same way using a hashmap.

```
interface IVertices {
  [index: string]: {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
  };
}

const geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(size, 0);
const positionAttribute = geometry.getAttribute('position');
const point = new THREE.Vector3();
const vertices: IVertices = {};

// Go thru all points and collect points on same vertex with a hashmap
for (let i = 0; i < positionAttribute.count; i++) {
  point.fromBufferAttribute(positionAttribute, i); 
  const key = [point.x, point.y, point.z].join(',');
  if (!vertices[key]){
    vertices[key] = {
      x: point.x += Math.random() * size * warpFactor,       
      y: point.y += Math.random() * size * warpFactor,
      z: point.z += Math.random() * size * warpFactor,
    };
  }
  // Modify all points on same vertex with same deformation
  const { x, y, z } = vertices[key];
  positionAttribute.setXYZ(i, x, y, z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
let geometry = new THREE.DodecahedronGeometry(size, 1);
let vertices = geometry.attributes.position.array;
for(let i = 0; i < geometry.attributes.position.count; i++){
  vertices[ i * 3 + 0 ] += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
  vertices[ i * 3 + 1 ] += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
  vertices[ i * 3 + 2 ] += 0 - Math.random() * (size / 4);
}
geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately typescript doesn't like this because geometry.attributes.position.array is typed as readonly